# Django Images not showing when DEBUG=False on Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku

I am trying to get images show up on website whenever a user uploads it, but they do not show up when DEBUG=False. The site got deployed successfully on Heroku. I am using Whitenoise and Gunicorn too.

Here are my configurations:-

settings.py

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

STATIC_URL = '/static/'


STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'



STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]


MEDIA_URL = '/images/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/images')
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('base.urls')),
]

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Procfile

```
web: gunicorn appname.wsgi --log-file -
```

requirements.txt

```
asgiref==3.3.4
astroid==2.5.6
colorama==0.4.4
Django==3.2.4
gunicorn==20.1.0
isort==5.8.0
lazy-object-proxy==1.6.0
mccabe==0.6.1
Pillow==8.2.0
pylint==2.8.3
pytz==2021.1
sqlparse==0.4.1
toml==0.10.2
whitenoise==5.2.0
wrapt==1.12.1
```

Comment: django only serves static files when running in debug mode ... you can add a custom url that serves the files through django or use nginx to route requests to <url>/static to a file directory and serve the requests from that

Comment: @JoranBeasley WhiteNoise allows your web app to serve its own static files, making it a self-contained unit that can be deployed anywhere without relying on nginx, Amazon S3 or any other external service. (Especially useful on Heroku, OpenShift and other PaaS providers.)

Comment: @JoranBeasley http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/

Comment: did you run collectstatic?

Comment: @JoranBeasley Heroku automatically does that for us, while deploying

Comment: @JoranBeasley All other static files like css and js are working fine, I am getting the issue with images only

Comment: I'm facing the same issue as @CutePanda after I turned `DEBUG=False` and run `collectstatic`. Did you find a solution?